# is there a SIP support for Flash?

Tags: flash, sip

Is there a SIP library to connect a flash application to a SIP server directly?(without passing from a rtmp media server)

Thank you

Comment: This should be feasible on the processing side, but even client sockets require jumping through hoops to bypass the security, and I'm not sure you'll be able to listen for the incoming RTP at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can write action script class and use [as3sip](http://code.google.com/p/as3sip/) library to serve your purpose .

Comment: thanks. as3sip is obsolete however, SIP-JS is probably works for me. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

I slept on it and that's my "final answer":
You can't accept incoming connections in flash, thus you'd need a special proxy keeping the signaling connection alive and assisting in symmetric RTP. The required infrastructure is not much different from running the SIP UA on the server, and passing the media streams to the flash client only, like red5phone does.

Also I expect you'd have trouble talking on a flash-only softphone with all the cooling fans blaring in your computer from the CPU intensive codec implementation in actionscript.